# Como colocar rotas com parâmetros opcionais asp.net-core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Queria que a minha rota fosse desta forma

```
 [HttpGet("APIPassword={APIPassword}/AvatarUUID={AvatarUUID}/Idioma?={Idioma}")]
```

Sendo que Idioma é Optional

```
[HttpGet("APIPassword={APIPassword}/AvatarUUID={AvatarUUID}/{Idioma:string?}")]
```

Mas quando coloco o URL quero mesmo manter este formato

> APIPassword=blblblb/AvatarUUID=dfsafadsfasf/Idioma=pt

O problema mais concreto é que o Idioma poderá ser introduzido

```
APIPassword=blblblb/AvatarUUID=dfsafadsfasf/Idioma=
```

E por isso estou a tentar resolver o problema tornando esse parâmetro opcional 
Queria portanto manter o **Idioma=** mesmo que não não venha nenhum valor à frente

Queria que fosse possivel manter a url desta forma  `APIPassword=blblblb/AvatarUUID=dfsafadsfasf/Idioma=pt`

Mas sendo que Idioma pode nao trazer valor

> APIPassword=blblblb/AvatarUUID=dfsafadsfasf/Idioma=

Comment: Veja se dessa forma funciona `Idioma={lang?}`

Comment: Poste como uma resposta

Comment: MAs eu queria que o caminho fosse APIPassword=blblblb/AvatarUUID=dfsafadsfasf/Idioma=

Answer (score 0):

É só utilizar o ponto de interrogação no paramêtro que pode ser opcional. No exemplo abaixo o `id` seria opcional.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Mas eu queria manter o caminho deste modo APIPassword=blblblb/AvatarUUID=dfsafadsfasf/Idioma=